# RegEx for matching everything except a text between two words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy, klipfolio

I have a text:

**"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"**

and I need to match everything except the text between a word and the first occurrence of a letter after this word as follows (in this case between brown and the first occurrence of "l"):

**"The quick brown lazy dog"**

I have tried some possible solutions but the closest match I have in my hand is exactly the opposite:

```
(?<=brown ).*?(?=l)
```

which matches **" fox jumps over the"**

#### EDIT:

I am using Klipfolio tool and the exact text I have is like this:

```
["String1: value1","String2: value2","String3: value3"]
```

And I want to match all except value1 and replace it with empty string.

Function I am using is [SUBSTITUTE_REGEX](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions#SUBSTITUTE_REGEX)

Comment: What language or tool are you using with your regex?

Comment: Simply replace your match with an empty string, now you will have the rest.

Comment: Inverse logic is not really that straight forward. For instance, if there is no `(?<=brown ).*?(?=l)` then you'd end up matching the entire string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using Klipfolio and I want to replace the needed match with empty string. The problem is that there is no regex function there only a regex replace function. (https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions#SUBSTITUTE_REGEX)

Comment: @PoulBak The thing is that I need to have only the match string and there is no regex function in Klipfolio, so I am using regex replace function (https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions#SUBSTITUTE_REGEX)

Comment: What you have is not a string but a JSON, please check what JSON features your tool has.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the simplest way is to do a string replacement.

To do the inverse is more involved and is done like this:

Find  `(.*?brown ).*?(l.*)|(.+)`
Replace `$1$2$3`

https://regex101.com/r/x8QW6r/1

Comment: Yeah I know this but the thing is that in Klipfolio (tool I am using) there is no regex replace (by group) function, so I need to use only the https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions#SUBSTITUTE_REGEX

Comment: @user11484870 - When I said _Replace_ it was just a suggestion. Substitute _join, concatenate, merge_ or any other word to describe what to do with the results.

Comment: It seems to me that original find `(?<=brown ).*?(?=l)` and replace with `nothing` is simpler.

Comment: Yes, like I said, the `(?<=brown ).*?(?=l)` and replace with nothing is the simplest, but the OP seems to want to match the inverse to _keep_, which doesn't make sense if he can't use the capture groups.

Comment: Nah, I meant to say _`like I said`_ because literally, I never said it, but if I felt sure it would be taken that way, I'd have said _as I said_, but that's a big  _if_ and I don't do big _if's_, like I said.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your original pattern and replace the matched part with an empty string `""`.

Alternative way to do this is to create two match groups, which you can then combine to get the wanted result:

```
(.*brown )(?:[^l]*)(.*)
```

> ```
> Full match  0-43   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
> Group 1.    0-16   The quick brown 
> Group 2.    35-43  lazy dog
> ```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v4IoY0/1/)**